# Composer network install: cannot get package for blockchain

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

- Composer version v.0.19.5 on Ubuntu
- composer network install is producing error. I have chacked all the similar posts regarding these keywords:  trying to start business network .... no valid responses from any peers ... cannot get package for blockchain 
  but it didn't help.

Network version is checked and it is correctly entered in the commmand. START and INSTALL commands are as follows:

- composer network install --archiveFile carauction-network1.bna --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1

  which resulted in: Successfully installed business network caracution-network1, version 0.2.4.-deploy.0
  Command succeeded
- composer network start --networkName carauction-network1 --networkVersion 0.2.4 --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw][2]

  resulted in: Starting business network definition. this may take a minute...
  Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
  Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message: cannot get package for chaincode (carauction-network1:0.2.4)
- I suspect it cannot find npm package. It says: "cannot get package for blockchain". Maybe it is not looking to the right directory. Anyway, where should be respective npm packages? Maybe the key is in the environment variables. My variables regarding Hyperledger are:

  ```
  GOPATH=/home/hyperl/go
  NVM_CD_FLAGS=
  NVM_DIR=/home/hyperl/.nvm
  NVM_BIN=/home/hyperl/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin
  PWD=/home/hyperl/.composer/cards/PeerAdmin@carauction-network5 ---> on samo of the trials the value was PWD=/home/hyperl
  PATH=/home/hyperl/bin:/home/hyperl/.local/bin:/home/hyperl/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/go-1.9/bin`
  ```

Comment: I suspect that your package.json version doesn't match what you've posted in your `network start` command. Check your package,json to verify. I think your `start` command should be something like `composer network start --networkName carauction-network1 --networkVersion 0.2.4-deploy.0 --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw  `

Comment: Thanks Paul O'Mahony. I've tried that earlier, but the same errror occurs. Additinaly, I have checked version using this command: composer archive list <archive name>. Error message does not reffer to the --networkVersion parameter but to the problem with the package "cannot get package for chaincode"

Comment: sir - based on the `network install` command RESPONSE you supplied above - it is not the same as the network name you are trying to `network start` - check out the response of `caracution-network1` ..if not that/ furthermore, the start response says it can't get the network cannot get package for chaincode `carauction-network1:0.2.4`

Comment: Paul thanks again for your comment. I did issued command with this parameter: --networkVersion 0.2.4-deploy.0
But I got the same error. The only difference is at the beginning where different version is stated in the message:
Starting business network carauction-network5 at version 0.2.4-deploy.0....

The rest of the message is having Error and it is the SAME as I stated in my Question earlier. It seems like composer is having problem with the --card parameter e.g. PeerAdmin@hlfv1.
Could it be that composer does not even reach the --networkVersion parameter.